Best practice to create ggplots inside of a function with empty arguments
I have a function, plot_fun where the arguments facet and fill sometimes are empty. In my real scenario I actually have many more arguments. I'm wondering what is a good way to have ggplot skip the arguments if they are empty? I have now written many if statements. Is this they way to go or is there a better and cleaner solution?
plot_fun <- function(data, x, y, facet = c(), fill = c()){
  
  ggplot(data, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color = .data[[fill]])) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~.data[[facet]])
  
}

x <- "Sepal.Width"
y <- "Sepal.Length"

plot_fun(iris, x, y, facet = "Species", fill = "Species")
plot_fun(iris, x, y, facet = c(), fill = c()) # does not work

EDIT:
The function aes_string works fine but it is deprecated. If someone has a solution that replaces aes_string, please post it.

What's wrong with if statements?  They are used quite a lot and are very easy to read and debug.

There’s probably no good way to avoid ifs (well, you could use dynamic dispatch on some proxy object via S3, but the resulting code would become much longer), but you don’t have to nest the ifs in a single, huge expression. You can break the logic apart into separate blocks that flow linearly, and end up with the simple expression ggplot(data) + selected_aes + selected_facet_wrap.

@KonradRudolph One much easier way was simply to replace aes with aes_string

As a note aes_string was deprecated in favor of aes(x = .data[[string_var]]

Yes, you can use if statements:
library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(data, if (length(fill) == 1L && is.character(fill)) {
    aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color = .data[[fill]])
  } else {
    aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]])
  }) +
    geom_line() +
    if (length(facet) == 1L && is.character(facet)) {
      facet_wrap(~.data[[facet]])
    } else {
      list()
    }
}


This is what I am trying to avoid

OK. I see no reason to avoid this.

I see no way to avoid this.

@Edward One way to avoid it was simply to replace aes with aes_string
